# ASP.NET MVC3 - Use DependencyResolver AND Windsor Castle: Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Can somebody shine a little light for me?

I've got my website all running using Windsor Castle. I have a controller factory and installers for controllers and services. All nice.

Now I've just created a `IDependencyResolver` implementing class called `WindsorDependencyResolver` with a straigh-forward implementation:

```
public class WindsorDependencyResolver : System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public WindsorDependencyResolver (IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.Resolve(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.ResolveAll(serviceType) as IEnumerable<object>;
    }
}
```

I've got it setup like so (global.asax):

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new WindsorDependencyResolver(kernel));
```

**And now what? When is this 'used'? Should I stop using `kernel.Resolve(someType)`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is the IDependencyResolver is what is used internally by MVC 3 to do Service Location/Inversion of Control.  So in order for your Controllers to get instantiated properly, and be able to inject whatever dependencies you have, you need to tell MVC how to talk to the container your using (Windsor in your case).

You would still want to use kernel.Resolve(someType) when you need to get something out of the container that is not injected for you via constructor/property injection.

Interestingly, the MSDN documentation points to [Brad Wilson's Blog Post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html) on the IDependencyResolver for details.

Comment: So this means that **I** will not use the DependencyResolver for things other than MVC3 internal services?

Comment: It's intent is to allow MVC to use your container of choice.  I guess you could use it yourself, but it's an extra layer of abstraction that you probably don't need to worry about in your code.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you already have a custom IControllerFactory. If so, just stick with it. It's a much better solution than the hack that is IDependencyResolver ([which has lots of problems](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/02/mvc-30-idependencyresolver-interface-is.html)).

Comment: I actually read about this before... But away from technical imperfections, what's going on here? What if I register another `IDependencyResolver` implementing class? How will the container behind `DependencyResolver.SetResolver()` know which one to use if they have overlap in the services they provide?

Comment: -1 Sorry to reply so late, but I think the conclusion of Mike Hadlows post is wrong. IDependencyResolver is not intended to be used by client code, rather it is intended to simplify extension of MVC.

Comment: If so, why is there a public Singleton through which it can be accessed? And why is MVC 3 being touted by Microsoft as 'now supporting DI'?